# Getting data from Rest into backbone collection

Tags: java, rest, backbone.js, resteasy, backbone.js-collections

My project is divided into four modules :
1. DataObject
2. Persistence
3. Services
4. Web

I have my collecetion in the web.

```
define(
    ['jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      //'app/models/model.driver'
    ],
function ($, _, Backbone, DriverModel) {
    var Drivers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        urlRoot: '/Driver',
        model:DriverModel

    });

    return Drivers;

});
```

And In my services i have a driver.java file like this.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/Driver")

public class Driver 
{
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


}
```

and my DriverService.java like this .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
//import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

//import org.json.JSONObject;


@Path("Driver")
public class DriverService 
{
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({"application/json"})

public String getDriver(@PathParam("id") String id)
{
    return "driver "+id;
}

@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Driver> getAllDrivers()
{
    List<Driver> driverList = new ArrayList<Driver>();
    Driver driver1 = new Driver();
    driver1.setId(1);
    driver1.setFirstname("111");
    driver1.setLastName("111");
    driverList.add(driver1);

    Driver driver2 = new Driver();
    driver2.setId(2);
    driver2.setFirstname("222");
    driver2.setLastName("222");
    driverList.add(driver2);

    Driver driver3 = new Driver();
    driver3.setId(3);
    driver3.setFirstname("333");
    driver3.setLastName("333");
    driverList.add(driver3);
    return driverList;
}
}
```

Now i need the data from the service to be loaded in to the collection and vice versa.
I google but didnt know how to proceed from here.
Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, new up an instance of your Drivers collection:

```
var drivers = new Drivers();
```

To retrieve a list of models from the server, call `fetch`:

```
drivers.fetch();
```

To persist the collection to the server, call sync:

```
drivers.sync();
```

Backbone also allows each model to be saved individually, which is handy since models are normally represented in individual views:

```
var driver = drivers.at(0);
driver.set('firstname', 'Jesse');
driver.save();
```

The `save` method can also be used to create a new model:

```
var driver = new DriverModel();
driver.set('lastName', 'Jackson');
// Note: Your server should return at least the id of the new object
driver.save();
```

To remove a model, call `destroy`. This will remove it from the server and from the collection it belongs to (if any):

```
var driver = drivers.at(0);
driver.destroy();
```

Comment: Leaving aside you're not actually connecting to a database, yea, it appears to be a good stub. You can try it out in your browser by visiting `/driver` and verifying you get your list of drivers.